# Match and replace a substring while ignoring special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently looking for a way to turn matching text into a bold html line. I have it partially working except for special characters giving me problems because I desire to maintain the original string, but not compare the original string.

Example:

Given the original string:

```
Taco John's is my favorite place to eat.
```

And wanting to match:

```
is my 'favorite'
```

To get the desired result:

```
Taco John's <b>is my favorite</b> place to eat.
```

The way I'm currently getting around the extra quotes in the matching string is by replacing them

```
let regex = new RegExp('('+escapeRegexCharacters(matching_text.replace(/[^a-z 0-9]/gi,''))+')',"gi")
let html= full_text.replace(/[^a-z 0-9]/gi,'').replace(regex, "<b>$1</b>")}}></span>
```

This almost works, except that I lose all punctuation:

```
Taco Johns <b>is my favorite</b> place to eat
```

Is there any way to use regex, or another method, to add  tags surrounding a matching phrase while ignoring both case and special characters during the matching process?

**UPDATE #1:**

It seems that I am being unclear. I need the original string's puncuation to remain in the end result's html. And I need the matching text logic to ignore all special characters and capitalization. So `is my favorite` `is My favorite` and `is my 'favorite'` should all trigger a match.

Comment: The whole point of the regex you've provided is to remove anything that is NOT 'a-z' (space) or digits. Thus only removing your punctuation: https://regex101.com/r/M9HrNF/1

Comment: If you successfully escape regex characters, why do you need to remove non alphanumeric+space?

Comment: @DoTheDew Right, as of now I'm removing the punctuation in order to get a match, but I desire to keep the punctuation in the end result, but have matching logic that removes special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing the special characters from the string being searched, you could inject in your regular expression a pattern between each character-to-match that will skip any special characters that might occur. That way you build a regular expression that can be applied directly to the string being searched, and the replacing operation will thus not touch the special characters outside of the matches:

```js
let escapeRegexCharacters = 
         s => s.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&"),
    full_text = "Taco John's is My favorite place to eat.";
    matching_text = "is my 'favorite'";
    regex = new RegExp(matching_text.replace(/[^a-z\s\d]/gi, '')
                .split().map(escapeRegexCharacters).join('[^a-z\s\d]*'), "gi"),
    html = full_text.replace(regex, "<b>$&</b>");

console.log(html);
```

Comment: This is almost exactly correct. However it fails when capitalization is not matching. So if the matching_text is "is My 'favorite'" it won't match, but I need it to. That was why I was using the `i` flag, is that possible to do using your character matching method?

Comment: Adapted: added the `gi` argument to the main `new RegExp()`.

Comment: I see, I tried to add the `gi` flag in the wrong spot. Thank you! This was very clever.

Answer (score 1):

Regexps are useful where there is a pattern, but, in this case you have a direct match, so, the good approach is using a `String.prototype.replace`:

```js
function wrap(source, part, tagName) {

  return source
    .replace(part, 
      `<${tagName}>${part}</${tagName}>`
    )
  ;
}
```

At least, if there is a pattern, you should edit your question and provide it.

Comment: That is true, except that replace will exact match special characters. So doing `"Taco John's is my favorite place to eat.".replace("is my 'favorite'", "ANYTHING")` will not work because of the extra single quotes in the 'part' variable.

Answer (score 1):

As an option, for single occurrence case - use **String.split**
Example replacing '**###**' with '**@@@**' :

```
let inputString = '1234###5678'
const chunks = inputString.split('###')
inputString = `${chunks[0]}@@@${chunks[1]}`
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to avoid using a capture group with the [`$&` replacement string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter), which means "entire matched substring":

```
var phrase = "Taco John's is my favorite place to eat."
var matchingText = "is my favorite"

var re = new RegExp(escapeRegexCharacters(matchingText), "ig");
phrase.replace(re, "<b>$&</b>");
```

(Code based on obarakon's answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing, the regex you could use `is my /w+`. You can use that in a replacer function so that you can javascript manipulate the resultant text:

```js
var str = "Taco John's is my favorite place to eat.";
var html = str.replace(/is my \w*/, function (x) {
  return "<b>" + x + "</b>";
} );

console.log(html);
```